# How to import the citation of arxiv papers to Mendeley that could produce the accurate citation format?

Tags: arxiv, reference-managers

I am using Mendeley to save my reference. And I find it seems that Mendeley does know the format of arxiv format.

I find many papers use a format like this:

```
Andrew Howard, Mark Sandler, Grace Chu, Liang-Chieh Chen, Bo Chen, Mingxing Tan, Weijun
Wang, Yukun Zhu, Ruoming Pang, Vijay Vasudevan, et al. Searching for mobilenetv3. arXiv 
preprint arXiv:1905.02244, 2019.
```

Here is the link for the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02244

I wonder how can I get it to Mendeley?

Thanks.

Comment: Some vital pieces of information are missing from the question. You talk about "how to import..." a paper into Mendeley. Both existing answers show you how to do this. However, you seem to be after *formatting a citation* which has nothing to do with the underlying information in the database (Mendeley). For the correct formatting you need to adjust the "Citation Style". Mendeley uses here the CSL standard but we don't know where you want to insert your citation.

Comment: @halirutan Sorry for bringing you confusion. I did chose the IEEE style when I compare these citations. I agree with the answer below show me how to import citations from arxiv to Mendeley, but as you can see, the output format is not accurate. That is why I asked this question because I thought I must did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems usually, I go to the Google Scholar and search the paper and from the results section, you can click on the cite button as shown in the picture and download the citation in any one of the formats. This downloaded file can be dragged and dropped to Mendeley.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I have just notice ShuffleNet paper is no longer a good example since it has been published. Now I have edited my question to a paper that is only on arxiv.

Comment: I have tried your method, however, it did not works very well. EndNote format did not work with Mendeley, RefWorks format required registration so I did not try. BibTex and RefMan format works with Mendeley, however, the reference style is still different: `A. Howard et al., “Searching for MobileNetV3,” arXiv Prepr. arXiv1905.02244, 2019.`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the common browsers, you can use the Mendeley Web Importer which is a plugin giving you a button to import the paper directly from the web-page.

Navigating to the arxiv paper you linked and clicking the Mendeley button in my browser opens a window and the imported information looks reasonable to me

[image: img]

The plugin lets you choose a Mendeley folder you want to use for the paper if you have structured your library into different categories and it will also download a PDF if available. Once you open the desktop Mendeley, everything is synced and you will have both the citation and the PDF locally on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your method, but I feel that Mendeley do not know the format for arxiv: `A. Howard et al., “Searching for MobileNetV3,” May 2019.`

Comment: Can you explain what the **output formatting** has to do with *importing* the complete citing information? In your database, you always want each and every name of the authors. When you prepare your citations for LaTeX (or god forbid Word), *then* you select a formatting style which will probably abbreviate names and only use the first author and then "et al.".

Comment: I think the problem is not `et al.`, it is I cannot get `arXiv 
preprint arXiv:1905.02244, 2019.`

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I'm a software engineer at Mendeley and I have actively worked on the Web Importer.**

*I feel that people before me have answered your question already and others have provided good insights as well. My intention here is to provide some additional technical details and not to promote Mendeley in any way.*

---

As halirutan mentioned, the Web Importer will be able to import the reference in your Mendeley Library. The Web Importer works with most common document identifiers such as DOI, ISBN and ArXiv (to name a few).

In this case it has found `arXiv:1905.02244v3` on the page and tries to find a match in the Mendeley Catalog. (If you're interested the API is available [here](https://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#metadata-lookup).)

[image]

What you can see in the screenshot is raw, *unformatted* metadata. You would get a similar display if it has found a DOI or an ISBN.

Once you chose to import that reference via the Web Importer, that reference *will* be in Mendeley.

Now as other people have mentioned, you can then process references in your Mendeley Library with a particular citation style of your choice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did import this reference into the Mendeley, and I chose the IEEE as citation style. Then I right click the reference in Mendeley, chose "copy as ->Formatted Citation". Here is what I get `[1] A. Howard et al., “Searching for MobileNetV3,” May 2019`. As you can see, the arXiv information is missing.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with Mendeley itself. This is probably due to that particular citation style.

Comment: But if I use NightRocker's method, I could get `A. Howard et al., “Searching for MobileNetV3,” arXiv Prepr. arXiv1905.02244, 2019`. Same IEEE style. Just a different method of importing.

Comment: I [searched for this paper](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=arXiv%3A1905.02244&btnG=) and clicking on the cite button didn't offer to cite this reference using IEEE.

Comment: Do I have to import as IEEE to output IEEE? I thought I could import as BibTex, then Mendeley could have all the reference information about the paper, then I can output different citation styles.